# setNavigationBar translucent pushes view down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a view with a transparent `UINavigationBar` and a `UITableView` about 10px below it. There's a `UIImageView` with a cool polygon image in the background that I'm animating in a parallax-y way for view transitions.

Here's the code for the transparent nav bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

***I'm not using storyboards at all for this project***

I also have a floating action button down in the bottom right.  The nav bar title `UILabel` I've added to the `titleView` is swapped for a `UITextField` for search functionality on tap of a right nav button.  When this happens, I'm setting

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;`

This all works well, except that by setting `translucent = NO` the view pushes the all of the content down by the height of the nav bar.

[image]
[image: Search Mode]

I can hack together some frame changes to compensate for this, but I was wondering if there was a more **standard practice** solution for this.

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you try to force Android's layout in your iOS app? Don't you think you should stick to the platform styles?

Comment: It's a good question.  I'm typically proponent of making apps look and feel "native."  However, in this case I really liked the UI that was designed for the Android version of this app by our designer.  Using Hangouts or Inbox on iOS is a joy and I believe that given the right attention this app will also look and feel great.

Comment: All right then :). It indeed looks quite neat. And maybe some new looks after seeing the same UITabBar in hundreds of apps will be quite refreshing. No offense btw

Comment: @Cabus - No offense taken.  It's a good discussion to have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The property you want to set is `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`, if this property is set to YES then your view will layout the same as if the navigation bar were translucent.

You mentioned that you're not using storyboards, but for others who do this can be set in the Attributes Inspector for the view controller under the 'Extend Edges' section by ticking the checkbox titled 'Under Opaque Bars'.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks @geraldWilliam